# Android Wear long running app - save battery

Tags: wear-os

I'm developing a map application for Android Wear with the possibility to log routes with the GPS. Since logging a route can go on for a while I would like to save as much battery as possible while logging but still, I need to show the current speed and distance to the user. My idea is to use the KeepScreenOn flag to stay in the current app and then lower the brightness of the screen to a minimum when logging.

The problem is I don't know if that's good enough for saving battery or if you guys have a better idea? Is it possible to have ambient mode for an app that is not a watch face?

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between a GPS guide (in your face, screen on, telling you where to go) and a GPS logger (no interaction needed until data is uploaded somewhere). I've actually thought of writing a walking (logging) app that just wakes up once a minute, grabs GPS, saves it, and goes back to sleep. In other words, it doesn't have to know every single move you make, just the general route. I managed to get an Arduino app lasting over a year on battery rather than 40-odd days, by using that method.

Comment: I see your point. Well, even if it's not a GPS guide I still would like to show information to the user while logging. The user will certainly be interested in staying in the app while logging for checking position/distance etc. from time to time. It feels like a bad user experience if the user has to open the app every time the watch has gone back to show the watch face. Even if that perhaps  saves most battery.